# What is the use of ToCoveoFieldName method in covoe search in hive framework?

Tags: sitecore8, coveo

As of now i am facing some problem with field bind issue while get the response from coveo, inside the this method ToCoveoFieldName is implemented. Any one can help me on this.

Code snippet

raw.<%= ToCoveoFieldName("field Name", false)

Comment: What problem are you having? It's not clear what your question is. Did you write this code? If not, where did it come from?

Comment: Code is all ready written and code snippet i have shard in my question, just want to know the use of this method and it will be return.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are having issues with this call, I am assuming that you might be migrating to the Coveo for Sitecore Hive Framework implementation, which mostly shifted from a back-end implementation to a front-end one for all of its major field logic.

This means that `ToCoveoFieldName` is not available any more on the server side. Instead, there is a JavaScript implementation of the same logic.

For instance, if you want to translate a field to the Coveo format, you can use `CoveoForSitecore.Context.fields.toCoveo("field name")`.

I can see in your question that you are within a result template, there are already two helpers to get you either the field name or the value.

`<div data-field={{= coveoFieldName("field name") }}>`

and

`<div>{{= coveoFieldValue("field name") }}</div>`. (This one is the equivalent of calling `raw[coveoFieldName("field name")]`)

Those helpers are explained in more details in the documentation, on the [Editing the Content of a Result Template page](https://docs.coveo.com/en/2834/coveo-for-sitecore-v5/editing-the-content-of-a-result-template) (for version 5.0+) and [Coveo Fields Resources Component page](https://docs.coveo.com/en/553/coveo-for-sitecore-v4/coveo-for-sitecore-legacy-search-ui-framework-coveo-fields-resources-component) (for versions <5.0 and 4.1+).